# Django-leaflet: map getBounds returning [object Object]

Tags: django, bounds, django-leaflet

I am using `django-leaflet` to display a map in a template, where the goal is to only display the coordinates of the visible area of the map when the user moves the map.

For this I'm using the `getBounds()` method, but the function only returns `[Object Object]`.

template.html:

```
{% load leaflet_tags %}
{% block extra_head %}
   {% leaflet_js %}
   {% leaflet_css %}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% leaflet_map "extent" callback="map_init" %}
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_script %}
  <script>
  function map_init (map, options) {
    map.on('moveend', function() { 
      alert(map.getBounds());
    });
  }
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Why is not showing the coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `getBounds()` returns a `LatLngBounds`, for viewing the coordinates it is necessary to convert to a string, using the method `toBBoxString()`.

```
function map_init (map, options) {
    map.on('moveend', function() { 
      alert(map.getBounds().toBBoxString());
    });
  }
```